# How can I put a Twitter share button in my Android application?

Tags: android, twitter, jtwitter

I am using Android 1.6. I want to integrate a Twitter button to share songs on my web-based application to my Twitter followers. For that, I integrated the jtwitter.jar file into my application.

But it is not accepting the username and password that I provide.

I am using the following statement to check the authentication:

```
twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has moved to [OAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq) so you can't log in with username and password like that anymore. [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php) supports OAuth.